# Error with clamd amavisd CentOS 7

Tags: email-server, centos7, amavis, clamav

I am getting issue with clamd and amavisd please see error message below
I am running an email server on CentOS 7.3..... amavisd and clamd seems working fine, but they keep jump up with errors every time before I send mails from my email server, and get errors if I send mails from Gmail to my email server.

```
Apr  4 15:37:49 mail postfix/smtpd[3367]: connect from mail-pg0-f45.google.com[74.12*.**.**]
Apr  4 15:37:49 mail postfix/smtpd[3367]: E42B1606A5C9: client=mail-pg0-f45.google.com[74.12*.**.**]
Apr  4 15:37:50 mail postfix/cleanup[3371]: E42B1606A5C9: message-id=<CAC-5EtvTiKHMGZXukkj=4rxhOKiD1f3oifaBE6QnmCnbgjM10A@mail.gmail.com>
Apr  4 15:37:50 mail postfix/qmgr[1374]: E42B1606A5C9: from=<wil*******@gmail.com>, size=2488, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  4 15:37:50 mail postfix/smtpd[3367]: disconnect from mail-pg0-f45.google.com[74.12*.**.**]
Apr  4 15:37:50 mail amavis[2097]: (02097-02) (!)connect to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock failed, attempt #1: Can't connect to a UNIX socket /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock: No such file or directory
Apr  4 15:37:51 mail amavis[2097]: (02097-02) (!)connect to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock failed, attempt #1: Can't connect to a UNIX socket /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock: No such file or directory
Apr  4 15:37:51 mail amavis[2097]: (02097-02) (!)ClamAV-clamd: All attempts (1) failed connecting to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock, retrying (2)
Apr  4 15:37:57 mail amavis[2097]: (02097-02) (!)connect to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock failed, attempt #1: Can't connect to a UNIX socket /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock: No such file or directory
Apr  4 15:37:57 mail amavis[2097]: (02097-02) (!)ClamAV-clamd av-scanner FAILED: run_av error: Too many retries to talk to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock (All attempts (1) failed connecting to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock) at (eval 129) line 613.\n
Apr  4 15:37:57 mail amavis[2097]: (02097-02) (!)WARN: all primary virus scanners failed, considering backups
```

Please help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr:

```
setsebool -P antivirus_can_scan_system 1
setsebool -P clamd_use_jit on

yum install clamav-scanner-systemd

cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
cp clamd\@scan.service clamd\@amavisd.service

systemctl start clamd@amavisd
systemctl enable clamd@amavisd
systemctl restart amavisd
```

---

## The long version:

My guess is you're getting a "no such file or directory" error because the socket `/var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock` doesn't exist, which in turn is because the clam daemon isn't installed or running and listening on that socket.

To fix, try

```
yum install clamav-scanner-systemd
```

...which includes the daemon, `clamd`.

By default, the service that comes with it, `/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamd@scan.service`, which in turn includes `/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamd@.service`, tries to open the wrong config file, by virtue of the **`%i`** in the service which is a placeholder for the instance name. To make the service use the amavis conf file instead, copy it to an appropriately instantiated unit:

```
cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
cp clamd\@scan.service clamd\@amavisd.service
```

(see *9.6.5. Working with Instantiated Units* in [the RHEL 7 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Instantiated_Units) for more on this)

Finally, try

```
systemctl start clamd@amavisd
```

and check it's running now, with

```
systemctl status clamd@amavisd
```

And finally enable it with

```
systemctl enable clamd@amavisd
```

Checking the contents of `/var/run/clamd.amavisd`, you should now find `clamd.sock` is present.

For good measure,

```
systemctl restart amavisd
```

And double check your logfiles that everything is working now.

If not, and if **SELinux** is enforcing, you may need to run the following first, for ClamAV and freshclam to function:

```
setsebool -P antivirus_can_scan_system 1
setsebool -P clamd_use_jit on
```

Comment: When I try cp clamd\@scan.service clamd\@amavisd.service:
cp: cannot stat ‘clamd@scan.service’: No such file or directory